# Database sync between SQL Server and Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, synchronization

I have two different application which run on different database, SQL Server and MySQL. Now I want real time data sync between SQL Server and Mysql - can anybody please tell me. I have already tried data migration, but it copies only data not sync data

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” question and is too broad, making it off-topic on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to make an attempt show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code can quickly get to the core of your problem and help us understand where you’re coming from.

If you really don't know where to start or need guidance and support consider mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: lots of similar questions asked....

Comment: @MitchWheat The magic of emoji! ✨⚡️!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at StreamSets.  Open source and can read the SQL Server change tracking (CT) tables and turn them into inserts, updates, and deletes to any database with a JDBC driver including MySQL.  It can also use the MySQL binlog to build data pipelines in the other direction.